# PyQt is executing my function multiple times after signal

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, slots

I'm building a pyqt Qwidget with multiple QcomboBox in which the user can add items at will. But I also want to give the user the option to delete any of the items by clicking a QPushbutton.

Because I can't know in advance which comboBox and item the user will want to delete, I created an event filter to find which object is being activated, and which item is being selected.

The code below works as expected, but the function `printevent` is being called an increasingly number of times, which will eventually turn my program very slow.

I tried to define `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()` to no avail.

What did I do wrong?

My code (for this example, I'm only showing one of the ComboBoxes):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys, os, json

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow,self).__init__(parent=parent)

        ### MAIN WINDOW ####
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(1016, 790)
        MainWindow.move(200,30)

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget()

        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))

        self.comboBox_nationality = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_nationality.setEditable(True)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox_nationality, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.comboBox_nationality.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self,obj, event):
        if  event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn:
            objt=str(obj.objectName())

            exec('self.' + objt + '.activated[str].connect(self.printevent)')
        return super(Ui_MainWindow,self).eventFilter(obj,event)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QString) # Doesn't change anything 
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot() # TypeError: printevent() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)   

    def printevent(self,item):
        print item


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    ex.__init__(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why don't you just connect all the signals in the normal way when the combo-boxes are created in `__init__`? The event-filter doesn't achieve anything (even if it worked properly). Use `combo = self.sender()` in the slot to get the widget that sent the signal.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was complicating waaayyy to much. combo =self.sender() does exactly what I wanted. Thank you!